# Gobblin Git clone error

Tags: linux, git, github, amazon-ec2

When trying to download and build Gobblin from git clone. By following, Download and Build Gobblin Locally
On your local machine, clone the Gobblin repository:

```
git clone git@github.com:linkedin/gobblin.git
```

It gives following error in my Amazon Ec2 instance.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:linkedin/gobblin.git
Cloning into 'gobblin'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.131' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

How to avoid that error message?

Comment: You need to configure your SSH keys to allow Git to communicate with the Gobblin server.  Please review the online documentation for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not about communicating with the goblin server, but communicating between your ec2 instance and github.com (through ssh)

When executing an ssh command (or a git clone ssh), ssh will look for a public/private key in your ec2 user account `$HOME/.ssh` folder.

Make sure you have followed "[Generating SSH keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/#platform-linux)" in order to have the right keys generated in your EC2 account, and to have the public key declared on your GitHub account.

The alternative would be to switch to https:

```
git clone https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin.git
```